# Better method to replace AsyncTask being deprecated to get data from server

Tags: rx-java, job-scheduling, threadpoolexecutor, android-jobscheduler, futuretask

I see there are several options to replace AsyncTask now being deprecated.

I get a little unsure or confuse or both which option is best to use.

Actually my asynctask get data form a server, which can take up to 2-5 seconds.

I see these options:

JobScheduler -
Thread -
Handler -
Executor -
ThredPoolExecute -
FutureTask -
Loader -
RxJava

Can someone tell me which is the best option? If any.

Comment: It really depends on your use case but in general, I would recommend: 1. Kotlin Coroutines, 2. FutureTask, 3. RxJava.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I investigate a little more and get to the same conclusion. I'll go with Ktolin